# Handling goto command errors in Batch

Tags: batch, batch-file

To get straight to the problem I need a **Batch file** **not to auto close** if my **goto command isn't valid** (goto Non existing place) and yes I have a pause after it

Here is the section:

```
set /p Command=
goto %Command%
pause
```

Thanks Pizza

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- This more secure version first gathers all labels in a string, one direclty following the other.
- The colon of the next label denotes the end of the previous.
- The string `%Labels%` and a colon is echoed to the findstr, the entered label is also appended with a colon so only complete labels are matched.

---

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "Labels="&For /f %%A in ('findstr /i "^:[a-z]" %0') Do Set "Labels=!Labels!%%A"

:redo
Set "Label="&set /p "Label=Choose label %Labels%:"
if not defined Label goto :Eof
Echo %Labels%:|findstr /i ":%Label::=%:" >nul 2>&1 ||(Echo invalid label %Label% & goto :redo)
goto %Label%
Echo we'll never reach here

:One
Echo Label One
goto :redo

:Two
Echo Label Two
goto :redo

:Three
Echo Label Three
goto :redo
```

Sample output:

```
> SU_1204527.cmd
Choose label :redo:One:Two:Three:one
Label One
Choose label :redo:One:Two:Three:two
Label Two
Choose label :redo:One:Two:Three:blah
invalid label blah
Choose label :redo:One:Two:Three:
>
```

Comment: Please could you explain how this is better/more secure that the one above if there's a good reason I'll use yours if not his is more compact :)

Comment: They are both mine :-) If there are two labels `:Test1 and `:Test2`` and the user enters `test` the other answer will fail - this one not.

Comment: I never noticed they were both by you. also thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 4):

```
:redo
set /p "Label=goto label:"
findstr /i "^:%Label%" "%~0" >nul 2>&1 ||(Echo invalid label %Label% & goto :redo)
goto %Label%
pause
```

**Edit** I have to admit that the batch will fail if the entered label is a beginning substring of a present label.